# Thread.sleep substitute in test script

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating a web site, in which the tutorial has exactly 10 identical "Next" buttons, which are triggering a short animation, before the next one appears, so I am using:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
}
```

In order to wait for each button to be clickable and click it.
I need to interact with other elements after exactly 10 clicks of the "Next" button.
Debugging this works fine, but running it clicks the elements several times, right after they become clickable, because of its animation (the code clicks a single element few times, so 2-3 clicks are made instead of 10).

Using a `Thread.sleep(5000);` in the for loop seems to work, because it waits until the animation is finished after each click, but I want a faster solution, not using `Thread.sleep();`

JavaScript executors and Actions don't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: what is element here and may be we can use index to check for specific "next" element

Comment: Hi @Nikolay, First Click all elements manually untill all 10 'next' buttons are become visible, then use the 'inspect element' functionality of browser on the 10th Next button and collect the actual 'html' content of the page. Then, paste that html content along the question. So that we could provide a way to automate the clicks on all next buttons one after another.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The question can not be more clear and the title is "Thread.sleep substitute", that's an actual problem, described with a very simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

Instead of

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

for the disappearance of web element and proceed further. You can provide the locator for animation that appears after click.

Comment: Using a: ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated seems to yield an Exception:

"Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by..."

As the animation is a smooth transactions between screens, while the element remains visible in all times.

Comment: then use visibilityofelement(locator) just before using invisibilityofElement

Comment: Still, the same exception occurs, as the element does not become invisible (it remains visible at all times).
Adding a visibilityofelement(locator) in the loop maybe adds another click or so, but still no 10 separate clicks.

Comment: Increase webdriver wait time in explicit wait

Comment: @AnkurSingh, even if I do that, the driver is going to click each element more than once.

Answer (score 0):

As @cruisepandey mentioned try to find locator for element You're trying to wait for (animation) find its locator (id, tag, ...) and use wait for:

```
public static boolean isElementNotPresent(MobileDriver driver, WebElement elementName, int timeout){
    try{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(elementName));
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
isElementNotPresent(driver, element, 30)
```